# Error xadmin django1.7.3

Tags: django

```
/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/bin/python2.7 

/home/lrqrun/workspace/timesheetv2/src/manage.py runserver localhost:8080
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lrqrun/workspace/timesheetv2/src/manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 137, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/lrqrun/.virtualenvs/timesheetv2_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

step by step white the docs `https://xadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html`  but found that error,

**Question :**

Is this  happening because of  django1.7.3 without the xadmin?

Comment: Have you run the "python manage.py syncdb" command after you installed xadmin. It seems your models are not loaded. Try running this command and see the results

Comment: it Solve！breach is'nt suppt django1.7

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. And I found a way to solve it in my case. My environment was django 1.7.6, xadmin 0.5.0. I changed the source file named models.py in xadmin.

The line `if django.VERSION[1] >4:` was changed to `if 4 < django.VERSION[1] < 7:`, then the issue was fixed.